# Approximation of function of $2n$ variables as product of $n$ separable functions of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, functions, approximation-theory

I have a function of $2n$ variables:

$u(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n)$

I am interested in the existence of approximations of such a function as a sum of products of paired variables. Let me write for brevity $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$. The approximations I am interested in have the form:

$u(x,y)=\sum_i f(x_i)g(y_i)$

Additionally, I can assume that $u(x,y)$ is monotonically increasing in all of the $y_i$ variables and I want the same to hold of all of the $g(y_i)$ functions. Otherwise, the $f$ and $g$ can be arbitrary. I can assume strong regularity conditions on $u$.

To be clear, I am not interested necessarily in constructing the approximation (although that would be neat), but in its existence and error bounds. I have found a similar question with approximating $u(x,y)$ as $f(x)g(y)$, but the only answer required discretizing the function and using single-value decomposition (low-rank approximation). This may be acceptable, but I am having a hard time generalizing to my case of $n$ variables. Also, it would be OK if the sum included more than $n$ terms, i.e., more than 1 term to approximate the contribution of each variable pair.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For a theoretical survey see Light, Cheney,
*Approximation Theory in Tensor Product Spaces* which concerns "the approximation of multivariate functions by combinations of univariate ones"

Practically, multivariate functions or data are often approximated using tensor product polynomials or splines.